What is this usage of 触れていました?
This is exchange between someone how paints and someone being shown  a painting:
綺麗。　やっぱりすごい才能です、いつから絵を？
…いくつだったか。でもずっと触れていました. 水彩をやり始めたのは最近です。　普段は主に油絵を
I don't understand, what is this usage of ずっと触れて? "I've been touching it all this time"?

You're close, but this (～に)触れる means "to be involved in ～", "to be exposed to ～", "to experience ～", etc. This person is saying that while they don't remember the exact age when they started drawing, they've been involved with it for a very long time.
